# cauchy sequence which does not converge in a metric defined by the multiplicity of a root

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find an example of a cauchy sequence which does not converge in the set of real valued polynomials over one variable $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with the metric $d(p(x),q(x)) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ is the largest positive integer $x^n$ such that $x^n$ divides $p(x)-q(x)$. Equivalently, $n$ is the multiplicity of the root $x=0$ of $p(x) - q(x)$.

My attempt was to use the cauchy sequece $(x^n)_{n=1}^{ \infty}$, but this turns out be convergent to the $0$ polynomial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take $$p_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$